# Class structure in Lua/Corona

Tags: oop, lua, coronasdk, metatable

So I'm working on a game in Lua and I'm trying to use metatables and classing but I think I'm importing my PHP knowledge and doing things slightly sideways.

```
-- Basic Monster
Monster = {}

function Monster:new(newX, newY)
    local newMonster = {x = newX, y = newY}
    setmetatable(newMonster, {__index = Monster})
    return newMonster
end

function Monster:moveTo(newX, newY)
    self.x = newX
    self.y = newY
end

function Monster:takeDamage()
    self.hitPoints = self.hitPoints - playerWeapon.damage
    if self.hitPoints <= 0 then
        self.die()
    end
end

function Monster:tap()
    self.takeDamage()
end

function Monster:die()
    self.removeSelf()
end

--Groblin
Groblin = {}
setmetatable(Groblin, {__index = Monster})

function Groblin:new(newX, newY)
    local groblin = display.newImage('assets/images/goblin.png');
    groblin.hitPoints = 4
    physics.addBody(groblin, 'static')
    gameGroup.insert(groblin)
    return groblin
end
```

I'm basically looking to be able to spawn several different types of monsters, and retain some base class functionality for them, but I'm uncertain in the above example how I tie in the base class to the `Groblin` class I made as I feel like I blew out that subclass altogether by what I'm doing inside of `Groblin:new`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want classes that you can subclass, try using [middleclass](https://github.com/kikito/middleclass). It's not very trivial to do subclasses in standard lua and middleclass has taken care of the boilerplate.

Also, make use of `local` -- use it anywhere it can be used.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this with your example would be:

```
function Groblin:new(newX, newY)
  local groblin = Monster:new( newX, newY )
  setmetatable(groblin, {__index = Groblin})
  groblin.image = display.newImage('assets/images/goblin.png');
  -- ...
  return groblin
end
```

Use the base class ":new()" method to construct the object and then add the unique fields for the subclass.  This insures the base class is properly constructed.  Re-setting the metatable to "Groblin" in the subclass constructor insures that any methods defined for the Groblin subclass are called if available, and where the Groblin table does not re-define a method the superclass method will be called.

It probably is better to use a library that provides a consistent approach for object creation and subclassing, but hopefully that gives you a better idea of how to do things manually.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.lua.org/pil/16.2.html for inheritance.
Pay a little attention on the explanation of how the use of self in Account:new works out best while SpecialAccount extends Account.

I generally follow a little different approach than the mentioned in above link. In the above approach -

```
SpecialAccount = Account:new()
s = SpecialAccount:new{limit=1000.00}
```

You are calling Account:new() twice, and more problem arises when Acoount:new() does some validaiton on constructor parameters and throws exceptions. For ex: ensuring that the limit passed in non-nil.

So I follow this

```
SpecialAccount = setmetatable({__index = Account})
```

Does the trick of allowing superclass constructor to be used in subclasses.

PS: I prefer to treat new function as a constructor. It essentially does the same job.